# Trigonometrical equations

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of the equation $\sin x + \sin 2x + \sin 3x = 0$.
I have started doing this problem by applying the formula of $\sin A + \sin B$ but couldn't generalise it. Please solve it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\sin x+\sin3x=2\sin\frac{3x+x}2\cos\frac{3x-x}2$$

We can also use $\sin x=\sin(2x-x),\sin3x=\sin(2x+x)$

Now $\sin y=0\implies  y=n\pi$

and $\cos A=\cos B\implies A=2m\pi\pm B$ where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers

Answer (score 0):

$(\sin x+\sin 3x)+\sin 2x=0$

$2\sin 2x \cos x+\sin 2x=0$

$\sin 2x(2\cos x+1)=0$

$\sin 2x=0$ or $\cos x=-1/2$

$2x=n\pi$ or 
$x=n\pi/2$ or $x= 2n\pi+-2\pi/3$

Answer (score 0):

You actually can also do this pretty well by just the simple addition formulas from geometry. By that I mean
$$
\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y) \\
\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)
$$
If you apply these to the expressions $\sin(2x)$ and $\sin(3x) = \sin(2x+x)$ you get after some calculation
$$
 f(x):=\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x) = \sin(x)\cos(x)(2\cos(x)+1)
$$
Since the function $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic it suffices to find the solutions on the interval $[0,2\pi)$. These are just given by the zeros of each factor, which are
$$A:=\{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2},acos(-0.5),-acos(-0.5)+2\pi\}$$
So the general solution set is given by $A + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.